# clipboard manager which has logging and sticky items?

Tags: windows, productivity, clipboard

I use ClipX as a clipboard manager but it crashes in some Office Applications and soemtimes doesn't show copied items in its list. I liked it because it has a logging feature and sticky items.

I am looking for other replacements with similar functionality. It needs to be quick and  with configurable hotkey.

Any recommendations?

Comment: You could try donating to the author of ClipX and then ask for the issues to be fixed after giving details repo. steps.

Comment: I already emailed him about the problems. He didn't respond.

Answer (score 2):

[ClipMate](http://www.thornsoft.com/) is very good. It is commercial, starting at $34.95. Its basically a database of your clipboard. By default it puts items in an Inbox and you can create further folders to file items in. There is a hotkey to the main window and you can assign shortcuts to individual items so you can quickly paste them. Also, you can search your clips and even write SQL to find stuff since it is running off DBISAM database.

There is a 30 day trial available, but the software seems to still be usable after the time limit has lapsed. There is also a Portable Apps version you can run off a pen drive, which I've found very handy.

I tend to use it for writing documentation and do screen captures as I'm installing apps and store various bits of related text, which I can then refer to later.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ArsClip](http://www.joejoesoft.com/cms/showpage.php?cid=97).  I'm not sure what you mean by "logging feature", so I don't know if it has that, but it's a pretty full-featured clipboard manager.

Comment: Logging copied text so I can go back to  text I copied any time in the past. It doesn't look like the newest ArsClip has it. Actually I used to use ArsClip before ClipX.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a list of [Clipboard Managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipboard_manager).  [ClipMate](http://www.thornsoft.com/) looks fully featured.

Answer (score 0):

Ditto will save your last X clipboard items

http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It doesn't have permanent clips

Answer (score 0):

[CLCL](http://www.nakka.com/soft/clcl/index_eng.html) is an awesome clipboard manager. Lots of configuration options and really easy to use, other ones I've tried couldn't compare. I think i have been using it for over 5 years now. It hasn't got sticky items functionality, but it has templates, it might be sufficient replacement.